# docker nginx letsencrypt doesn't create the certificates ssl

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

I use **letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion** to generate the ssl certificates for my sites, it has always worked but since 15 days, I can no longer create new ssl certificates.
The only change made is the update of the image from v1.11 to v.13.
Thanks a lot for your help!!

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro

  nginx-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    container_name: nginx-gen
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro


  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./app/docker-gen.cfg:/app/letsencrypt_user_data:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: "nginx-gen"
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: "nginx-proxy"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: wordpress
  learning:
    external: true
```

docker images :

```
jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion   latest              xxxxxxxx        32 hours ago
```

docker-compose logs nginx-letsencrypt:

```
nginx-letsencrypt    | Reloading nginx docker-gen (using separate container nginx-gen)...
nginx-letsencrypt    | Reloading nginx (using separate container ec5f65a8ecc84fc03c31032c88db2c8c9cf814c983bed9d3b074a6311230459c)...
nginx-letsencrypt    | 2020/06/11 22:46:45 Generated '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 24 containers
nginx-letsencrypt    | 2020/06/11 22:46:45 Running '/app/signal_le_service'
nginx-letsencrypt    | 2020/06/11 22:46:45 Watching docker events
nginx-letsencrypt    | 2020/06/11 22:46:45 Contents of /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification '/app/signal_le_service'
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 1: [[config]]: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 2: template: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 3: dest: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 4: onlyexposed: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 5: notifycmd: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 7: [[config]]: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 8: template: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    | /app/letsencrypt_user_data: line 9: dest: command not found
nginx-letsencrypt    |
Every 2.0s: = true                                          2020-06-11 22:46:46
nginx-letsencrypt    |
nginx-letsencrypt    | sh: =: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

removing this line it works (docker-compose.yml):
- ./app/docker-gen.cfg:/app/letsencrypt_user_data:ro